# Docker node status changes from "Ready" to "Down" after restarting or even when mac sleeps and I login again

Tags: macos, docker, containers

I have the following situation in my mac:
output of the following command:

```
$ docker node ls

ID                           HOSTNAME         STATUS  AVAILABILITY  MANAGER STATUS
p675ega5ujku8v5f4n4gghd5d *  moby  Ready   Active        Leader
```

But when my mac sleeps or restarts and i login again, the status becomes Down
Then i have to leave the swarm forcefully and join again each time :(
That is the only hack I have figured out.
I was thinking that it might be due to the reason that everytime i login, a different ip address is allocated from a pool of ips.
Please help on how to avoid the node from going down.

Comment: I am experiencing this too

Comment: This was helpful: http://blog.programster.org/docker-swarm-cheatsheet

Comment: Thanks for the link. will have a look